# how to check if a date variable string has the correct regex?

Tags: python-3.x

Sorry I am a beginner in python and regex

I have a date string:

```
date_string = '2018-05-01 00:00:00'
```

I would like to check that date_string is in the right format with a regex which is the case in our example

I believe the regex for this format is:

(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2}) (\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})

I would just like to check if a date corresponds to this regex:

Example :
for
date_string = '2018-05 00:00:00'

=> variable has the wrong format

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex is fine.  To do this in practice, you might use `re.search`:

```py
date_string = '2018-05-01 00:00:00'
if re.search(r'^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}$', date_string):
    print("VALID")  # prints VALID
else:
    print("INVALID")
```